# Func<T,bool> Extend the condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have a Method which accepts `Func<T,bool>` condition as a parameter and I want to expand the condition like:

```
public T SomeClass.GETConditionalValue(x=>x.Id==id).ToList();
```

now this `SomeClass.GETConditionalValue` expects a parameter `Func<T,bool>` condition which
I want to modify it without disturbing the `SomeClass.GETConditionalValue`

Something like this:

```
public T SomeClass.GETConditionalValue(ApplyFilter(x=>x.Id==id)).ToList();
```

where

```
public Func<T,bool>ApplyFilter<T>(Func<T,bool>condition) where T: GenericCLass
{

   return condition (+ some new condition in & or || block) 
}
```

**UPDATE :- ** cant use delegate here , throwing Cannot convert lemda expression to type bool cos its  not a deligate type

```
   public IEnumerable<T> GetEntities<T>(Func<T, bool> condition) where T : ITableEntity, new()
        {
            if (applicationFilter == null)
                return tableContext.CreateQuery<T>().Where(condition).ToList();
            return tableContext.CreateQuery<T>().Where(applicationFilter).Where(condition).ToList();
        }
```

my call is

```
 var mappedApplications = userToMdouleRepo.GetEntities<UserMappingToModules>(x => x.UserEmail == email)
```

here i want change it like

```
 var mappedApplications = userToMdouleRepo.GetEntities<UserMappingToModules>(ApplyAdditionalFilter(x => x.UserEmail == email)).ToList()
```

Comment: In other words, `ApplyFilter` shall return a delegate?

Comment: yeah the problem is you can expand func conditon like  (condition && x=>x.Name=="Hi")

Comment: @Fildor i cant use deligate

Comment: You _are_ using delegate: [Func<T,TResult> **Delegate**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: i mean i cont extend the condition its throwing error

Comment: :D Ah, now I get it ... haha. Can you specify which version of dotnet core you are using? I was under the impression, Jonathan's answer should work.

Comment: @Filder so the ApplicationFilter is in ASp.net MVC NF-4.7.2 and the Repo is Class Lib NF-2.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
public Func<T, bool> ApplyFilter<T>(Func<T, bool> condition) where T: GenericClass
{
    return t => condition(t) (+ some new condition in & or || block) 
}
```

For example:

```
public class GenericClass
{
    public string Name { get; }
}

public Func<T, bool> ApplyFilter<T>(Func<T, bool> condition) where T: GenericClass
{
    return t => condition(t) && t.Name == "SomeName";
}
```

Comment: did not worked mate Cannot convert lemda expression to type bool cos its not a deligate type

Comment: @RAHULSR Can you post your lambda? This definitely should compile: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VSrSPh

Comment: Please look at it now

Comment: @RAHULSR I meant your `ApplyFilter` implementation i.e. the place that's causing the compiler error.

Comment: @MongZhu no issues there T is ApplicationBaseEntity which inherits ITableEntity so , and also my Filter MEthod is also using ApplicationBaseEntity

Comment: @MongZhu i am using it on Azure Table Storage